# how to convert condition IN list into string oracle using parameter plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I need to convert a condition IN  list to a list of string using parameter.

from:

:p_parameter in ('a','b','c')

to:

:p_parameter = (a,b,c)

For example
select kod from dual where kod in(:p_parameter)

if the input is :p_parameter in (a,b,c)
then the output show

```
kod
------
a
b
c
```

Anyone got the idea?

Comment: What would p=(a,b,c) mean?

Comment: p is: p_parameter. i want to input data list with convert to: p_parameter = a, b​​, c. You know how to do it in the oracle?.

Comment: First hit on google: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=oracle+in+list+variable

Comment: i have try search but the artikel is not what i want. too complicated. did you get another artikel about that?.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **[LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm)** will help you

```
    SELECT col1
           LISTAGG(p, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p) AS p
    FROM   p_tgable
    WHERE  p in ('a','b','c')
    GROUP  BY
           col1;
```

Comment: i have try but but the error messsage appear. The parameter list in where clause. do you know about that?.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with [Nested Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDHIGFH) collection type.

First declare a custom nested type, let's name it STRINGS_TYPE:
`create type STRINGS_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);`

Then you can compare collections for equality, for example this will return 1 because these two collections are equal:

```
select 1 from dual 
where STRINGS_TYPE('a', 'b' , 'c' ) = STRINGS_TYPE('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Order does not matter, collections are equal,  returns 1:

```
select 1 from dual 
where STRINGS_TYPE( 'b','a',  'c' ) = STRINGS_TYPE('a', 'b', 'c')
```

These two collections are not equal, nothing  is returned:

```
select 1 from dual 
where STRINGS_TYPE( 'x','y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c' ) = STRINGS_TYPE('a', 'b', 'c')
```

In your code  bind `:p_parameter` parameter like this:

```
String[] pArray = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};

String selectSQL = "select 1 from dual where  :p_parameter = STRINGS_TYPE('a', 'b', 'c')";

Connection connection = database.getConnection();  

oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement preparedStatement = (oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement )connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);

oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor descriptor =  oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("YOUR_SCHEMA.STRINGS_TYPE", connection);
oracle.sql.ARRAY pOracleARRAY = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(descriptor, connection, pArray);
preparedStatement.setARRAY(1, pOracleARRAY);

resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
// ...
```

Comment: i have try your example but the result is zero.no output. The problem is the parameter. i need the result show the input a,b,c

Comment: I think the problem was in `STRINGS_TYPE(:p_parameter)`. It should be just `:p_parameter`  
So I corrected 
`String selectSQL = "select 1 from dual where  STRINGS_TYPE(:p_parameter) = STRINGS_TYPE('a', 'b', 'c')";` 
to 
`String selectSQL = "select 1 from dual where  :p_parameter = STRINGS_TYPE('a', 'b', 'c')";`.

Comment: i have try your sql but the warning message show is "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got SPTB.STRINGS_TYPE"

Comment: Here you can download my working example: https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B2QnTQBhT9z7djVKdDBNYXI1NW8&export=download